# Android AlertManager through reboots, updates, etc

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alert

A major component of our Android app is to send notifications to the user at particular times using an [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

When a user creates a new 'record', we queue up an alarm on the spot. So, if one downloads the app, opens it up, and creates one or more records, all notifications are queued just fine. However, this is the most simplistic use case.

Another use case is when the user has already created a record, and reboots their phone. In this case, the *queued alarms would be lost*. All records are stored in the database and the correct notification time can be resolved after the fact. The solution here, then, is to add a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` events. When the phone boots, we queue a notification for all outstanding records.

My question is if these these two use cases cover everything? If not, what other cases do we need to think about and what might be some solutions? For example, will the queued alarms be blasted away when we push an update to the app? Are there other situations in which queued alarms might be lost?

Answer (score 2):

You're right you'll need to listen to `BOOT_COMPLETED` events (you'll also need to add `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission to actually receive them).

And to handle application updates, you can use a receiver with the following lines in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnUpdadeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    <data android:scheme="package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the code:

```
public class OnUpdadeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{     
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {  
    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())) 
    {
      if (intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart().equals(context.getPackageName())) // check if event is about our app
      {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }      
}
```

If your minSdkVersion is 12 or above, you can use `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` action instead, which notifies only about your package being replaced, in difference to all packages when using `PACKAGE_REPLACED`. So with `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` you won't need the `intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart().equals(context.getPackageName())` check.

Other common issue in similar apps is how to ensure the app receives the actual notification events to show them to the user:

- If your events happen at specific times known beforehand, then setting alarms via AlarmManager with RTC_WAKEUP flag should be enough.
- Otherwise it might be necessary to keep a service running in background to monitor the events - and to do this reliably, you'll have to keep a notification visible in the notification area, or ask users to install a widget on the home screen, to ensure the OS doesn't terminate the service (more detailed info in [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method description).

Comment: Good to know about the `PACKAGE_REPLACED`, I'll look into that more. I'm less concerned about actual implementation and more concerned about what I need to be considering: what are the cases where queued notifications might be blasted away. I'm still not clear if this will happen during an update, will it?

Comment: Your application has to be terminated for an update, so, yes, assuming your queued notifications live only while application runs, they will be blasted away.

Comment: Sorry, In android terms, I think I meant 'alarm' where I've said 'notification'. When I queue an *alarm* using the `AlarmManager`, are all those alarms deleted when the application is terminated? Termination doesn't include `pause`, so what does qualify as *termination*? (I'll update my question now)

Comment: Good question. This case is not described in documentation. I can suggest to experiment by registering an alarm, reinstalling the app and checking if alarm is still triggered.

Comment: Application termination is not an issue for AlarmManager, since PendingIntent is still valid after termination. And judging by PendingIntent source code, it looks like there's a high chance it will live past reinstall as well, but this certainly has to be checked on practice first.